# TYPO3 and MySQL database on separate servers

Tags: mysql, typo3, ssh-tunnel

Is it possible to run TYPO3 (6.0) and MySQL on separate servers with TYPO3 connecting to the database through a SSH tunnel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be possible. However, it depends how your web hoster manages access from remote servers. 
For TYPO3 4.x, it's something like that in `localconf.php`:

```
$typo_db_username = 'mysql_user';
$typo_db_password = 'mysql_password';
$typo_db_host = '127.0.0.1:12345';
$typo_db = 'mysql_dbname';
```

For TYPO3 > 6.x, it's in `LocalConfiguration.php`:

```
return array(
  [...]
  'DB' => array(
  'database' => 'mysql_dbname',
  'host' => '127.0.0.1:12345',
  'password' => 'mysql_password',
  'username' => 'mysql_user',
  ),
  [...]
);
```

Where `12345` is the local port you used to set up the tunnel:

```
ssh -L 12345:127.0.0.1:3306 ssh_user@remoteserver.com
```

On most servers, you can use `localhost` instead of `127.0.0.1`.
IMHO, the security bottleneck is how the remote MySQL server handles incoming connections. I guess you can also set ths in via the install tool.

**EDIT**: Changed the host according to hints from comments.

Comment: As the connection is through a SSH tunnel, I reckon `$typo_db_host` should be set to `localhost:XXXX` where **XXXX** is the port of the tunnel set up on the TYPO3 machine.

Comment: Many thanks for the helpful reply! The proposed solution has worked well. Two small adjustments: The file is now called `LocalConfiguration.php` and `$typo_db_host = 'localhost:12345';` in my case had to be replaced by `'host' => '127.0.0.1:12345'`.

Comment: Jeppi, I guess it depends on your server configuration - but `127.0.0.1` is the safer solution, kudos.

Comment: i need help with something similar. I'm trying to access database on same server but by a dif name thatn typo3 one of course. I can't find any php files to edit in my typo3 directory that any where near resemble this? Where are you editing this stuff?

Comment: Scratch that, i found `LocalConfiguration.php`!!! But what good does editing it do? I still don't know how editing this will get me the typoscript i need on my backend to display the data i pull, or how to pull it!?i posted my question ealier,  COULD YOU PLEASE LOOK AND HELP?
 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16988100/typo3-can-i-pull-from-another-database-on-the-same-server