# Typo3: Where is Domain Modelling view?

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.1.x

It was suggested to me, in order to do what i asked in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16988100/typo3-can-i-pull-from-another-database-on-the-same-server), I need to use [Extension Builder](http://typo3.org/extension-manuals/extension_builder/2.5.2/) to make an extension. So I decided I would try. I'm stopped at the very start.  The first line states "`To create a new Extension, go to the Domain Modelling view.`" ... OK? Where is it?

I don't see anything for this on the back end. I don't see a directory extension for it. I don't see controller file for it. I don't see a tab on the back end view. Where is it!?

I've googled, but all that does is take me to documentation on MVC of Typo3, which from what I have experienced, has 0 MVC to it. It's just a giant PHP array with a complicatingly long list of php classes manipulating the array. I could be wrong, but that's what it looks like.

So, if i'm going to do this the Typo3 way and not good old fashioned PHP, where is the "`Domain Modelling View`"?

---

I found [this screenshot](http://typo3.org/typo3temp/tx_terdoc/documentscache/e/x/extension_builder-2.5.2/docbook/pictures/10000000000005A00000038423BDE922.png) of it in use. However, even after having installed the extension, I don't have "Extension Builder" in my "Admin Tools". I'm so confused???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log out of the back-end after installing. Log back in.

Look in the Admin Tools panel on the left and there at the bottom is the "Extension Builder".  Apparently, the first time you click it you get an intro page. In the middle of the page is a line that says something like "Go to Domain Modelling View".

Comment: Did you try a full cache delete before relogin? I'm just intrested that relogin was the only way to do it or not.

Comment: @AndrásOttó Yes I had. And still was frustrated. Feel even more stupid for not having relogged sooner. I literally tried everything!

Answer (score 0):

Just refresh the backend after installing the extension builder